# no access-control allow-origin header error, but the call is not cross-site

Tags: asp.net, xss

I don't understand the following error, as I'm not doing anything that leaves the domain. The call is from **example.com** to **example.com**.  Or is the `www` prefix treated as a separate domain from the bare domain?

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.example.com/foo/SearchHandler.ashx.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.
>   Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Origins are defined as protocol, full host name and port:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

So yes, example.com and www.example.com are treated as two different origins, and as such you would need Access-Control-Allow-Origin.